# Ruby twitter client

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm trying to create a ruby-based twitter client where I can post my status from command-line using ruby. I'm trying to understand the oauth right now, and it confused me a little bit. If I'm building a web application, I can provide a callback url when the request token is complete. How would I do that from the command-line? I don't want ruby to print out the authorized and copy and paste the url and click 'Allow' to get the token. I found something about out-of-band exchange or PIN. How would I do that with OAuth library in ruby, please thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the callback url mechanism, you application should be a `web application`. It seems you are developing `desktop application` and if that's the case, you should follow "**PIN code**" flow by supplying an `oauth_callback_url` of "oob" (out-of-band) when you request token. Like this,

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?**oauth_callback=oob**

If you properly set a header of this HTTP request (setting HTTP header is the key part of OAuth and I think you already know how to do this), Twitter will give `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_verifier`. Let's call this token `"request_token"`. You need it to get `"access_token"` later.

Once you have `request_token`, you need to open web page with the below url

> http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=**request_token**

This will open the authorization page and let a user to decide whether the user wants to allow your application to access his or her Twitter account. If the use says okay, then Twitter gives **PIN code**. You need to allow a user to type the PIN code so that you can save it.

Now, it's time to get another token (`"access_token"`) by using your `comsumer_key / secret`, `request_token` and the `PIN code`. You should set header with all these values correctly and do HTTP request again with this url,

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

If Twitter accepts your "access_token" request, it will give you `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret`, `user_id` and `screen_name`. Let's call this token `"access_token"`. Now, you can perform any OAuth required Twitter API by using `access_token` and `its secret (oauth_token_secret)`. You can save the two values in a file and keep using them whenever you need to access the user's Twitter account. The values will be always valid until the user revokes the access to your application.

I don't know Ruby but if you know how to perform HTTP/HTTPS  requests (GET / POST) with custom headers in Ruby, this PIN code flow should work fine if you follow Twitter API document carefully. Good Luck!

Comment: I just want to note something that, if you want to create a twitter client to use alone or just a single-user application, you could just use My Access Token which is already set from http://dev.twitter.com/apps. So, I don't have to worry about OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

It will ask for the PIN code until you specify the oauth_callback when getting the request token, **not when forwarding the user to the authorization url**

@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
      TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, 
      TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, 
      {:site=>"https://api.twitter.com"})

@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token( **:oauth_callback => CALLBACK_URL** )

This was the result of surfing several hours of incomplete documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use Twitter gem, it will make things easier for you. http://rdoc.info/gems/tweeter/2.0.0/frames